# Grouping a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-formbuilder

I have an input where the user can enter a country and a city separated by a comma to a list of countries and cities.
The list should then be displayed in a way that each city is listed under its country group.

I'm struggling to find the right way to construct my form.

```ts
form = this.fb.group({
    newEntry: [],
    cityToFind: [],
    citiesList: this.fb.array([]),
});

get citiesListForm(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('citiesList') as FormArray;
}

get searchInput(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('cityToFind') as FormControl;
}

get newEntryFormControl(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('newEntry') as FormControl;
}

getCountryFormArray(country: string): FormArray {
    return this.citiesListForm.get(country) as FormArray;
}

addCountrySection(country: string): void {
    this.citiesListForm.push(
      this.fb.group({
        [country]: this.fb.array([]),
      }),
    );
}

addCity(country: string, city: string): void {
    this.getCountryFormArray(prefix).push(
        this.fb.control(nr),
    );
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addCountrySection('USA');
    this.addCountrySection('DE');
    this.addCity('DE', 'Berlin');
    console.log(this.getCountryFormArray('DE')); // This is returning null
}
```

Is the form structure correct? Can someone provide me with an example how to write the template.

Comment: How would you like your final object to look like?

Comment: @OwenKelvin something like this: ```{ citiesList: [{de: ["Berlin"]}, {usa: []}]}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem with your approach is that you are mixing `FormArrays` and `FormGroups`.

Consider your desired structure

```
{ 
  citiesList: [         // <--------FormArray
    { de: ["Berlin"] },  // <--------FormGroup
    { usa: [] }
  ]
}
```

So If I would like to access the "de" element I would need to do something like

```
  form[citiesList][0].de
```

So for the reactive form this would be `form.get("citiesList").controls[0].get("de")`

I have illustrated this in [This stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mgnlhn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

This would work but I think a better approach would be to simply remove the outer array and have below

```
{ 
  citiesList: { 
    de: ["Berlin"],
    usa: [] 
   }
}
```

With this you will be adding controls with country as property.

Another approach to consider may be to use the formArray like below

```
{ 
  citiesList: [ 
    { country: "DE", cities: ["Berlin"] },
    { country: "USA", cities: [] },
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FormArray` is a variation of `FormGroup`, however the difference is that the data gets serialized as an `Array` rather then an `object` when using `FormGroup`. This might be useful when you don’t know how many controls you require (when your creating dynamic forms)

Here is Angular's definition of [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)

> A FormGroup aggregates the values of each child FormControl into one object, with each control name as the key. It calculates its status by reducing the status values of its children. For example, if one of the controls in a group is invalid, the entire group becomes invalid.

> A FormArray aggregates the values of each child FormControl into an array. It calculates its status by reducing the status values of its children. For example, if one of the controls in a FormArray is invalid, the entire array becomes invalid.

Below I've added a snippet of the code with comments to help you understand what's happening.

```ts
export class AppComponent {

  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    newEntry: [],
    cityToFind: [],
    citiesList: this.fb.array([])
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  // Get your cityToFind FormArray
  get citiesListForm(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('citiesList') as FormArray;
  }

  // Get your cityToFind FormControl
  get searchInput(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('cityToFind') as FormControl;
  }

  // Get your newEntry FormControl
  get newEntryFormControl(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('newEntry') as FormControl;
  }

  // Get the Country FormArray
  getCountryFormArray(country: string): FormArray {
    const index = this.citiesListForm.controls.findIndex(control => control.get(country));
    return this.citiesListForm.controls[index].get(country) as FormArray;
  }

  // Check if Country Exists
  doesCountryExist(country: string): Boolean {
    return this.citiesListForm.controls.filter(x => x.get(country)).length === 0 ? false : true;
  }

  // Add the Country to citiesList Form
  addCountrySection(country: string): void {
    if (!this.doesCountryExist(country)) {
      this.citiesListForm.push(
        this.fb.group({
          [country]: this.fb.array([])
        })
      );
    }
  }

  // Add either country or country and city
  addCountryAndOrCity(country: string, city: string = null) {
    if (!this.doesCountryExist(country)) {
      this.addCountrySection(country)
    }

    if(city !== null){
      this.getCountryFormArray(country).push(this.fb.control(city))
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Add just countries
    this.addCountryAndOrCity('USA');
    this.addCountryAndOrCity('DE');

    // Add countries and cities
    this.addCountryAndOrCity('DE', 'Berlin');
    this.addCountryAndOrCity('DE', 'New City 1');
    this.addCountryAndOrCity('USA', 'New City 2');
    this.addCountryAndOrCity('GB', 'leicester');
    this.addCountryAndOrCity('GB', 'london');
    this.addCountryAndOrCity('GB', 'Manchester');

 
    console.log('DE has ' + (this.getCountryFormArray('DE').length) + ' cities');
    // DE has 2 cities

    console.log('GB has ' + (this.getCountryFormArray('GB').length) + ' cities');
    // GB has 3 cities
    
    console.log('USA has ' + (this.getCountryFormArray('USA').length) + ' cities');
    // USA has 1 cities

  }
}
```

I agree with [Owen Kelvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13680115/owen-kelvin) when he says your mixing the two and the structure he's mentioned is cleaner and less confusing in my opinion.